# code will not insert category into sqlite3 db

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

**`category` declaration**

```
connection.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE category (
    cat_id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    cat_name            TEXT NOT NULL
    );
''')
```

**logic:**

```
  for cat in categories:
        '''
        debugging only
        '''
        print(category)
        try:
            connection.execute("""
            INSERT INTO category
                (cat_name)
                VALUES (?) """, (cat)
            )     
        except:
            print('Error Occurred inserting category: {}'.format(cat))
```

I tried printing out the value of `categories` and got what I inputted:

```
 ['Valu1', 'Valu2', 'Valu3', 'Valu4']
```

When I execute, it hits the `except:` block . I verified the `category` exists

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In this part

```
connection.execute("""
INSERT INTO category
    (cat_name)
    VALUES (?) """, (cat)
)
```

you need a comma after cat, like this

```
connection.execute("""
INSERT INTO category
    (cat_name)
    VALUES (?) """, (cat,)
)
```

so it will be a tuple.

Oh, and in response to your comment question about how to get error messages, I'm going to put this here so it will get formatted correctly (when I put it in a comment below the indentation was lost):

```
except Exception as e:
    print('Error Occurred inserting category: {}'.format(cat), e)
```

Comment: It fixed it when I ran it here, at least, though maybe there are other problems in the parts of your code that you didn't post. Another problem I see is that I believe that where you have "print(category)" you want "print(cat)". Here's a way to see the error message (though comments don't let you format as code, maybe I should add it to my answer, too, so it will be easier to make out):

    except Exception as e:
            print('Error Occurred inserting category: {}'.format(cat), e)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check. First is the `connection` variable, the actual connection or the cursor (`c = connection.cursor()`). Second, you forgot to commit the changes `connection.commit()`.

Comment: So try printing 'c' above ?

Comment: you use the `execute` command on the cursor, and then commit the changes to the actual connection. Code would be: 1. declare connection to file. 2. Create cursor. 3. Use `execute(blablabla)` on cursor. 4. Commit to connection. [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: If I try to print out connection, it says: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1097213b0>, so it has a cursor object to work off of.

Comment: Do you have the `conn.commit()` line after creating the table categories. Assuming `conn` is your <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x1XXXXXXX>.

Comment: Yes I have conn.commit() after I create the table: category, as I said, I've verified it creates the tables, they actually do exist.

Comment: However, when I create the tables/db i use: conn = sqlite3.connect('my.db')
    connection = conn.cursor()

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the error message is pretty much useless. Try printing the message from the exception on your `except`.

Error:
`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.`

Adding `(cat,)` is the correct solution.

`cur.execute("INSERT INTO category (cat_name) VALUES (?)", (cat,))`

Comment: Can you show me how to use exception handling in sqlite3 for my script? it doesnt appear evident here.

Comment: You can just take out the `try/except` part. Or you can do: 
`except Exception as e:
print e.message
`